# SQLCMD - Access is Denied After Running Script

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm working with a vendor about this, but a supplied script that they have to run to upgrade their software, after running, ruins access to SQLCMD.

Before running the script I can open a Command Prompt window > SQLCMD > Drops me in.

After running their scripts, when attempting to do the same thing, get the error:
Access is Denied

I've tried dropping a copy of SQLCMD.exe from a known good working server into same location where the affected server was, but even trying to manually invoke it from the location, receive a:
"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item".

Going to permissions > Security, it has all the same permissions as the known good working file, as is the entire directory path. So obviously osmething deeper, but I cannot / do not know where to start to diagnose.

Comment: What kind of script?...T-SQL? If so, then that would be where to start but it would be unlikely any pure T-SQL script is affecting Windows permissions for SQLCMD.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. All I know is that the script calls for SQLCMD to  connect to the database after providing all the connection details.

Comment: The vendor provided you a script and you don't know what kind of script (or even the file type of it) is?

Comment: It's a .bat file that  calls other .bat files which call other .bat files which all run SQLCMDs. I know enough of the basics to know some of what they're doing but SQL isn't my bread and butter.

Comment: Ok, that's *more* helpful at least. Unfortunately no one here is likely able to help you navigate what the Vendor's batch file code is doing (short of seeing the code). Your best bet is to ask the Vendor, and specifically mention prior to their upgrade, you were able to access SQLCMD and after you're getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: I've tried rolling back my test server and now it's not happening when I run the script, but I have a version of the server where it is broken. So I have no clue how to try to fix it. I've tried to repair Windows, tried reinstalling the SDK, new versions of it, etc...

Comment: Yea unfortunately that sounds like something outside the scope of what anyone here would be able to help with. If you're lucky, maybe someone on the Networking Stack Exchange would have an idea, but seems pretty obscure and localized unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah. The ONLY fix I've found so far, has been as OS Upgrade...